# What will be the decimal value in register r23 after the execution of each of the following independent sequences of instructions

Tags: avr

What will be the decimal value in register r23 (if interpreted as a two’s complement number) after the execution of each of the following independent sequences of instructions?

```
sec(opcode) 1001 0100 0000 1000
clr(opcode) 0010 01Dd dddd DDDD (DDDDD=ddddd)
ror(opcode) 1001 010d dddd 0111

sec 
clr r23
ror r23
```

Answer: -128

Can someone tell me how to get the -128 (with clear explanation) from the instructions above?

Comment: How is this connected to the C language?

Comment: When did SO become a CPU emulation service?

Comment: What did you discover when you used a debugger?

Answer (score 2):

Look up these instructions on the [website](http://www.atmel.com/webdoc/avrassembler/avrassembler.wb_instruction_list.html) or in the [manual](http://www.atmel.com/images/Atmel-0856-AVR-Instruction-Set-Manual.pdf). Pay particular attention to what happens to the status register.

Note that it is not necessary to know the opcodes, or that CLR is just EOR with the same register twice.

Also note that -128 is 0b10000000 in binary.

The answer is so trivial that you won't be helped by someone reading the manual for you. The only benefit will come from you reading the manual yourself.